# Linux/OSX/Windows - Waiting end of process

Tags: linux, windows, macos, pid, child-process

Under OSX, there is "open -W" which allows to wait the end of an executable.

What is the equivalent instruction for windows ?

Linux does have this non-blocking behaviour with programs like sublime-text (subl). How does it do that (execv ?)

Basically, I'm trying ,within a C program, to launch an executable and wait until it ends up.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. It's totally possible for a parent process to wait on its child process in Windows.

Comment: `open` talks to launch services to get the relevant program to open a document. It's not the same as running a command. linux uses `xdg-open` to accomplish something similar, and in a windows command shell you would use something like `start /wait` on the document to get the same behaviour. However your question really doesn't have enough to help compose any sort of meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the edit, under linux, you're looking at:

```
childpid = fork();
if (childpid) {
    execve("program", argvp, envp);
} else {
    int status;
    pid_t pid = wait(&status);
```

}

under windows, you need to use [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to create the process, and then use [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to wait for the process to terminate; e.g.

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = {0};
STARTUPINFO startupInfo = {0};
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
bool status = CreateProcess(L"Program", L"args", 0, 0, 0,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 
    0, 0, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
if (status) {
    WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, a parent process can wait for a child process to terminate by using the wait or waitpid system call. For more finer process synchronization, use semaphores.